# How to play a raw audio file using gst-launch?

Tags: audio, alsa, pcm, gstreamer

I'm using gst-launch-0.10.

I created a pcm file (at least, I think I have) from a mp3 file using the command:

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=my-sound.mp3 ! mad ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! 'audio/x-raw-int, rate=8000, channels=1, endianness=4321, width=16, depth=16, signed=true' ! filesink location=out.raw
```

I now have an out.raw file.

To test if everything worked, I'd like to play it back.
I tried this (among other things):

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=out.raw  ! capsfilter caps="audio/x-raw-int, rate=8000, channels=1, endianness=4321, width=16, depth=16, signed=true" ! alsasink can-activate-pull=true
```

but I get this error everytime:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0: Filter caps do not completely specify the output format
Additional debug info:
gstcapsfilter.c(393): gst_capsfilter_prepare_buf (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0:
Output caps are unfixed: EMPTY
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

"Filter caps do not completely specify the output format"? What is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, adding the `audioconvert` filter before `alsasink` made it work. According to gst-inspect, the audio format specified was compatible with alsa. So I guess it was a problem with the soundcard, and that `audioconvert` somehow converted the data to something my sound card could handle. Just a guess.

I also removed the `can-activate-pull=true` option. The sound quality with this option activated was very bad. I'd like to understand why.